# Scala capture object reference while still using extractors

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka, case-class

Is there any way to make this:

```
// I'm using akka, perhaps there's a magic variable inside receive I can use
def receive = {
  case Message(channel, data, sender) => {
    // do stuff with channel, data, sender
    // Oops, I want to reuse message, so I have to build a new one
    foo ! Message(channel, data, sender)
  }
}
```

Into something like this:

```
def receive = {
  case x: Message(channel, data, sender) => {
    // do stuff with channel, data, sender
    // Now I want to reuse message
    foo ! x
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `@` to also capture the full object.

```
case x @ Message(channel, data, sender) => {
    // do stuff with channel, data, sender
    foo ! x
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You're really on top of the basic Scala questions!